# How can a module defined in a .ml file reference itself

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

I am trying to define a `Point` module that defines a type to represent 2d points.

I would also like to include a submodule `Point.Set` so that `Point.Set.t` is
a type meaning 'a set of Points'. That seems logical and convenient, but I am not able to figure out how to make the 'circular' reference that this involves.

I tried this:

*file: point.ml* (implicitly defines a 'Point' module)

```ml
type t = {x: int; y:int}

let compare {x=x1;y=y1} {x=x2;y=y2} = ...implementation omitted for brevity...

module Set = Stdlib.Set.Make(Point)
                         (*  ^^^^^ Internal path Mylib__Point is dangling *)
```

When I `dune build` the `Mylib` project/library this is in. I get an error:

```
Internal path Mylib__Point is dangling.
  The compiled interface for module Mylib__Point was not found.
```

I am not entirely sure what the error really means, but I gather it probably has *something* to do with the fact that we are trying to reference the `Point` module from within itself. And maybe that is not allowed?

I can work around this by instead defining a separate 'pointSet.ml' file and in there have `include Set.Make(Point)`. Now I have a module called `PointSet`. That is okay, but I still would find it a bit more 'aesthetically pleasing' if `Point.Set` could be a submodule of `Point` instead. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with circular dependencies in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260/dealing-with-circular-dependencies-in-ocaml)

Comment: No I don't think so, that is about recursive types and recursive functions. This question about references at the module level. I know how to deal with recursive type / recursive functions. But I have no idea how to deal with the circular reference in my example, which I think is of a different nature.

Comment: The answer does contain a link to something about recursive modules but the link is broken. That may contain some hints as to what an answer to my question might be. But that answer in itself doesn't really address my question directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind a little bit of boilerplate, I think this solution may suit you:

`point.ml`

```ml
module Point = struct
  type t = { x : int; y : int }

  let compare { x = x1; y = _y1 } { x = x2; y = _y2 } = x1 - x2
end

module Set : Set.S with type elt = Point.t = Set.Make (Point)

include Point
```

You'll have access to `Point.Set` and since `point.ml` includes the module `Point` at the end of the file, you won't have to do `Point.Point.compare ...` in other files.

---

[EDIT]

I previously made the modules mutually recursive but in this case it's useless. If you need them to be mutually recursive you'll have to explicit their signatures:

`point.ml`

```ml
module rec Point : sig
  type t

  val compare : t -> t -> int
end = struct
  type t = { x : int; y : int }

  let compare { x = x1; y = _y1 } { x = x2; y = _y2 } = x1 - x2
end

and Set : (Stdlib.Set.S with type elt = Point.t) = Stdlib.Set.Make (Point)

include Point
```

Comment: The `open` will not affect other modules. Did you mean `include Point`.? There is also no recursive dependency between `Point` and `Set`, thus you can define `Point` (or `Core`) and define `Set` after `Point`.

Comment: You're right, I meant include. And for the recursive part, I simplified an example I had where Set and Point were mutually recursive but in this case it's useless. Thanks for the review

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know a module doesn't have a name for itself. You can make a module (a struct) just for the purpose of supplying it to the functor Set.Make:

```
type t = { x : int; y : int }
let compare a b = compare a b

module Set =
    Set.Make(struct type nonrec t = t let compare = compare end)
```

Comment: Woah! It looks like that works :-). I guess we are lucky that `Set.Make` only expects a small amount of things (2 instead of 15). It isn't very elegant to have to say 'copy these things from my context' one by one. But at least it works... which is great.